# C# basic hello world not running

Tags: c#, console-application

[image: New Error][image: Output from code when ran]

I am just trying to run a basic hello world program (or any program for that matter) and no matter what I do I always get this cmd terminal that pops up (even if I don't use Console.out.write() or any code at all) when I hit any key to continue the terminal closes and my code never runs. Please any help would be greatly appreciated I can't seem to find anybody else having this issue. I've attached a picture of the code used as well as the terminal that pops up (basically a screenshot of what happens after I click run).

Edit: I changed it to static and am now receiving this error, I placed it in a brand new project and everything there is no other files so not sure why I'm getting this, thank you all for the help!!

Comment: It's better if you copy and past the code and any error message or output into the question instead of using images.

Comment: Try making your Main function a static method

Comment: My best guess is that your debugger is running a `Main` method in a different class since the one you show is not `static` and if that where the entry point you'd get a compilation error

Comment: In the bottom pane, where it says "Show output from", change that from "Debug" to "Build". Your `Main` isn't static, so your project will not compile (unless you have another `Main` somewhere), so you're probably running an old version of your code

Comment: Can you post another screenshot of your Visual Studio w/o the console window open? I'd like to see what else you have going on in this project. Adding `static` to the `main` method is going to be required, but I don't think that's your only problem.

Comment: Also, stop debugging and look at the "Error List" (in the bar at the bottom, click View -> Error List if isn't not showing). It will show you any compiler errors

Comment: You're missing `static` and `string args[]` that must be there by default.

Comment: @Coke I tried that and it didn't change anything and even suggested I remove it as it's an unused argument

Comment: Note that you've got yourself a Unit Test project, not a Console Application project (that detail was obscured by the console window in your first screenshot). I suggest you create a new project, and make sure you select "Console Application"

Comment: @canton7 Thank you very much! That was the issue it works now!

Answer (score 5):

Your main method inside class Program should be a static method. - This is your entry point.

Add the static keyword to your main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This alone will not fix the problem as it should give a compilation error if the entry point class doesn't have a static `Main` method.

Comment: @juharr If that happens, VS gives you a dialog saying "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?". If you click "Yes", then it will just run the last-successful build, which might be what OP's seeing

Comment: @canton7 Yeah, making this one static should result in a different compilation error about there being more than one entry point, so the OP will need to make the other `Main` method (where ever it might be) not static.

Comment: he might've had a previous build with the keyword static and later when he updated his code .. he might've somehow deleted the static keyword ... not sure though..

Comment: Right, if the OP had an empty Main, and they changed it to not be static when they added the code then selecting continue with previous build could cause this, but it's hard to tell without more info.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but now am getting another error unfortunately (see edited post)

Comment: @mizuprogrammer it looks like you created a new unit test project, instead of a console application.

Answer (score 1):

As @canton7 say, this code don't compile, then you run a old compiled version.

You can change this behavior in Tools -> Options :
[image]